# Can I monitor boost::lockfree::spsc_queue from a third thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, lock-free

I have one thread producing data onto a `boost::lockfree::spsc_queue`, and one thread consuming data. Can I have a third thread monitoring the queue using `read_available` or `write_available`? I am not interested in an accurate count, but I would like to know if the queue is steadily growing, as that means the consumer is not keeping up. The docs state that `read_available` is:

> Thread-safe and wait-free, should only be called from the consumer thread

(https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html)

What happens if a third thread tries to call `read_available`? If it will just get an inaccurate count, that is fine. If it could get random numbers, or break things in some way, then I think I will keep a count using a `std::atomic<int>`.

Comment: The details of what happen might depend on the compiler-generated asm for the target machine, and what kind of runtime reordering it can do.  I don't know, but if the docs say it's not supported you'd have to investigate or experiment.  Presumably calling `read_available()` while the reader is in the middle of dequeuing  an element is not safe for some reason.  You'd have to look at the implementation to see if that just means a potential off by one or what.

Comment: No. It's a SPSC queue and the constraints are clearly document. "What happens if..." - All these question get: [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) - it's literally not defined. If you're lucky you get racy data. If you're not lucky, anything could happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could have the reader thread check the queue size occasionally (like every 1000 items), and publish a `std::atomic<int> qsize`** (with a `mo_relaxed` store) that the 3rd thread could read.

Use a non-atomic counter that's private to the reader.  Reader decrements it, and resets it to 1000 + publishes when it hits zero.  Keep it in a cache line that the writer doesn't touch so there's no extra contention at all except every 1000th item you do a store that needs an RFO before it can commit the value to the cache line.  But it's a write-only store, not a RMW, so the store buffer can hopefully hide the latency.  (Except on x86 where the next atomic RMW is always a full barrier so it will have to wait for that store to commit.  But it's only every 1000 dequeue operations so it's barely going to slow the reader down any more.)

Having a `std::atomic<int>` that both reader and writer atomically inc/dec will make them contend with each other more than a SPSC queue.  Not quite as bad as competing for a lock, but I expect it would be much worse than what I suggested.

---

**The details of what happen might depend on the compiler-generated asm for the target machine, and what kind of runtime reordering it can do.  I don't know, but if the docs say it's not supported you'd have to investigate or experiment if you want to risk it.**

Presumably calling `read_available()` while the reader is in the middle of dequeuing  an element is not safe for some reason.

You'd have to look at the implementation to see if that just means a potential off by one or total garbage.

Comment: Thank you. My current attempt is to get the reader thread to store the results of `read_available` to a `std::atomic<int>` after every read. This is then polled at a set interval by a monitoring thread (on a time scale of many queue operations). Are `atomic<int>`s  slow enough that one would want to have a non-atomic counter to prevent frequent writes to an atomic int?

Comment: In this line: "Keep it in a cache line that the writer doesn't touch", I understand the part about not letting the writer touch, to avoid contention. But how would one keep it in a cache line? Are you referring to a specific command to load to cache? I thought that kind of thing was best left to the OS to sort out.

Comment: @MartinCook: a non-atomic counter that stays hot in cache is super-cheap, saving the work of calculating the available space as well as publishing.  `avail.store(result, std::memory_order_relaxed)` is trivially cheap if it hits in cache (which it can as long as the other thread hasn't polled it since the last write).  If you use a memory-order stronger than release (i.e. the default seq-cst), you'll get a full memory barrier which costs a lot locally even if it hits in cache.  Especially with gcc on x86, which uses `mfence` instead of storing with `xchg`.

Comment: @MartinCook: re: separate cache line: I'm saying don't put it in the same `struct` as the queue pointer itself, or next to any other globals the writer wants to access.  i.e.  watch out for false sharing.  A local in the reader's stack would be great, and probably a `static` or global variable is fine if it's not declared right next to the queue control block.